# Angular.js directive com templateURL dinâmico

Tags: angularjs

```
create.directive('renderInputs', [ function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            alert(attrs.type);
            return '../templates/inputs/type-' + attrs.type + '.html';
        }
    }
}]);

<render-inputs  type="{{ p.input.type }}"></render-inputs>
```

- Erro: 
  `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ../templates/inputs/type-{{ p.input.type }}.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)`

Estou com problemas em fazer em carregar um template dinâmicamente.
Meu `alert` está retornando `{{ p.input.type }}`, na realidade era pra retornar um tipo com esses valores: radio, checkbox, etc.
por exemplo: `'../templates/inputs/type-radio.html'`

Answer (score 1):

Isto está acontecendo porque o valor está sendo passado literamente, sem avaliação no contexto de escopo.

Em teoria você pode utilizar `$scope.eval(attrs.type)` para avaliar a expressão: entretanto esta não é uma solução muito elegante.

Utilize um template com `ng-include`, ao mesmo tempo que força a avaliação da expressão `{{ p.input.type }}` via marcador de escopo `@`. Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
var create = angular.module("create", []);

create.controller("testController", function ($scope) {});

create.directive('renderInputs', function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope: { type: "@type" },
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           
               scope.contentUrl= function() {
                    return 'type-' + scope.type + '.html';
               }
           },
           template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl()"></div>'
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/ng-template" id="type-radio.html">
    <input type='radio' />
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="type-text.html">
    <input type='text' />
</script>

<body ng-app='create'>
    <div ng-controller="testController">
         <render-inputs type='radio'></render-inputs>
         <render-inputs type='text'></render-inputs>
    </div>
</body>
```

Esta resposta é uma [adaptação deste post no SO original.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)